# rake script weird in cmd.exe, works fine in ruby.exe

Tags: rake, cmd, rakefile

I have this rakefile that works fine when called from a "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" instance, but fails when called with `rake.bat`. This means I can't get it to work on Jenkins at all using the Rake build step plugin.

From what I can tell, it's the `rake/clean` task that's messing up and deleting all files in a "/Core" directory. I've explicitly excluded this from the `CLEAN` filelist, but when called from `rake.bat`, this is completely ignored.

What could possibly be the cause for this?

Edit:
OK, more info. `CLEAN.exclude('**/core')` is ignored the first time it's run in the Ruby shell too, but subsequent runs are fine. That explains why `rake.bat` is a problem 100% of the time.

I'm using rake 0.8.7, but the same thing happens with 0.9.2. Ruby version is 1.9.2p290. albacore version is 0.2.7. Windows 7 x64 (same thing happens on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it.
Should've realised it earlier, but it's mind-boggingly weird.

fails the first time: `CLEAN.exclude("**/core", "**/bak", "**/~")       # a comment here`

this always works: `CLEAN.exclude("**/core", "**/bak", "**/~")`

I guess I'm henceforth removing all comments that are not on a single line in my rakefiles...